# Checking for Server Response Code 200 in C

Tags: c

So i have this script that sends Barcodes to a server (which should respond with a code 200 upon receiving the Barcode). 
What i want to know is how i can check this in my C Script. 
e.g.
if (ServerResponse == 200)
printf(your Barcode has been transmitted)

sry for my bad english and my really bad C knowledge

```
#include <stdio.h >
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])

{ 
while (1)
    {
    char buf[256],syscmd[512];
    int i;

    /* Get next barcode */
    printf("Waiting for bar code [q=quit]:  ");
    if (fgets(buf,255,stdin)==NULL)
        break;

    /* Clean CR/LF off of string */
    for (i=0;buf[i]!='\0' && buf[i]!='\r' && buf[i]!='\n';i++);
    buf[i]='\0';

    /* q = quit */
    if (!strcmp(buf,"q"))
        break;

    /* Build into curl command */
    sprintf(syscmd,"curl \"http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=%s\"",buf);

    /* Execute--this will wait for command to complete before continuing. */
    system(syscmd);
    } 
return(0);
}
```

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code for getting the HTTP return code, the look into interpreting the result of the `system(...);` call.

Comment: This might be more suited to a shell script than a C program

Comment: If you are hell-bent on using curl, the [man page for curl](http://man.cx/curl) indicates a range of exit codes for various scenarios. Also, this blog post is relevant: [How To Display Just The HTTP Response Code In Command Line Curl](http://beerpla.net/2010/06/10/how-to-display-just-the-http-response-code-in-cli-curl/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into popen, since curl will default to printing the data to stdout (if not, look at man curl), popen will let you read that data.

the HTTP header (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) describes where exactly that code is. Also, I would suggest ensuring that the data does not overflow syscmd.

```
char *base = "curl \"http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=\"";
if (strlen(base) + strlen(buf) > 511)
{
     fprintf(stderr, "Error! buffer overflow would have happened!\n");
     return 1;
}
else
{
     sprintf(syscmd, "curl \"http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=%s\"", buf);
     FILE *p = popen(syscmd, "r");
     //check the output for HTTP code 200 here 
}
```

Hope that helps you.

EDIT: Checking the code is pretty simple too

```
//assume you are using the code from above
int code;
fscanf(p, "HTTP/1.1 %d", &code); //either HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0 depending on your server
if (code == 200)
{
    printf("Yupp, all good :)\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Server did not do so well with that request :(\n");
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, that does help but im a noob at C and still dont know how to extract the 200 from the output.

Comment: that works!! wow you're great thanks a lot for the help. I have to learn a lot about C!!